# How to increase loading time of post request in IIS windows server 2019

Tags: django, iis, loading, windows-server-2019

I have deployed Django on a windows server using IIS Windows Server 2019. When I submit the form, the time limit of the backend process is 100 Seconds, But after 40 seconds, IIS server responds with error 500. How can I increase this loading time of IIS.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, you can increase timeout to give application more time to load resources.

- Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
- Expand the local computer node, expand Web Sites, right-click the appropriate Web site, point to Manage Web Site, click Advanced Settings.
- In the Advanced Settings window, expand Connection Limits, change the value in the Connection time-out field, and then click OK.
  [image]
- Open IIS.
- On the left side, select"Application Pools"
- On the right side,right-click this application pool and select Advanced Settings.
- In    the advanced settings, increase "Idle Time-out (minutes)".
  [image]

Add this in web.config

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```